# Is there a way to run code after reactor.run() in scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

I am working on a scrapy api. One of my issues was that the twisted reactor wasn't restartable. I fixed this using `crawl runner` as opposed to `crawl process`. My spider extracts links from a website, validates them. My issue is that if I add the validation code after `reactor.run()` it doesn't work. This is my code:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from twisted.internet import reactor
from urllib.parse import urlparse

list = set([])
list_validate = set([])
runner = CrawlerRunner()


class Crawler(CrawlSpider):

name = "Crawler"
start_urls = ['https:www.example.com']
allowed_domains = ['www.example.com']
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_links', follow=True)]
configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})

def parse_links(self, response):
    base_url = url
    href = response.xpath('//a/@href').getall()
    list.add(urllib.parse.quote(response.url, safe=':/'))
    for link in href:
        if base_url not in link:
            list.add(urllib.parse.quote(response.urljoin(link), safe=':/'))
    for link in list:
        if base_url in link:
            list_validate.add(link)


runner.crawl(Crawler)
reactor.run()
```

If add the code that validates the links after `reactor.run()`, it doesn't get executed. And if I put the code before `reactor.run()`, nothing happens because the spider hasn't yet finished crawling all the links. What should I do? The code that validates the links is perfectly fine I used it before and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do that with `d.addCallback(<callback_function>)` and `d.addErrback(<errback_function>)`

```
...
runner = CrawlerRunner()
d = runner.crawl(MySpider)  
def finished(d):            
      print("finished :D") 
def spider_error(err):
      print("Spider error :/")        
d.addCallback(finished) 
d.addErrback(spider_error)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Sorry to ask, but is there an alternate way of achieving the same result?

Comment: @MeZo  1.[Scrapyrt](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyrt) 2.[Klein](https://github.com/twisted/klein) 3.[Arachnado](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/arachnado)

Answer (score 0):

For your ScraperApi you can use [Klein](https://github.com/twisted/klein).

> Klein is a micro-framework for developing production-ready web services with Python. It is 'micro' in that it has an incredibly small API similar to Bottle and Flask.

```py
...
import scrapy 
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from klein import Klein
app=Klein()
@app.route('/')
async def hello(request):
    status=list()
    class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name='test'
        start_urls=[
            'https://quotes.toscrape.com/',
            'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
            'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/3/',
            'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/4/'
            ]
        def parse(self,response):
            """
            parse 
            """
            status.append(response.status)
    runner=CrawlerRunner()
    d= await runner.crawl(TestSpider)
    content=str(status) 
    return content
@app.route('/h')
def index(request):
    return 'Index Page' 
app.run('localhost',8080)
```